# How to print the vowels in mips assembly

Tags: mips

I need print the vowels and here is my code and it prints from A to Z.
any idea how i should change my code that it prints only vowels.
thanks in advance.

```
.text
main:
li  $s0,0x41


for:
move    $a0,$s0 
li  $v0,11      
syscall 

addi    $s0,$s0,1

li  $t0,0x5b
blt $s0,$t0,for     
j   stop
stop:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with this:

```
.data
vowels: .asciiz "aeiou"
.text
```

Now write a loop to print each byte of `vowels` in turn.